# Adding excluded gradle dependency when running from IntelliJ

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

My Gradle (6.x) project builds a zip file with a well-known directory structure:

```
+-- bin
|      scripts
|
+-- etc
|      configuration files from resources
|
+-- lib
       jars
```

I don't want the files from resources included in the application jar, so I do this:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            exclude '**'
        }
    }
}
```

This gives me the desired result, but it has a very annoying side effect: when I run the application from IntelliJ, it can't find the files under resources. I have to either copy them somewhere in the classpath under build or comment out the lines above while testing (and sometimes people forget to uncomment them when checking in code...)

Manually adding resources in the project structure in IntelliJ works, but every time it imports the Gradle project, this gets overwritten.

Is there a convenient work around for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation for the [Java plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html), there is a `processResources` task which may be of use here.

> Copies production resources into the production resources directory.

I think maybe move the exclusion into the task configuration itself:

```
tasks {
    processResources {
        exclude '**'
    }
}
```

`processResources` is a [`Copy`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html) task type. Untested, but that may work.

Comment: It works the same way as the sourceSets/exclude, i.e. it doesn't include the resources in the jar file, but it has the same side effect when I run from the IDE - the resources are not found...